# TCP recvfrom() doesn't store 'from'

Tags: c++, tcp, ip-address, recv

I'm making a server program using TCP and I want to get the IP adress of the sender of the message I just received. Here's my code:

```
case FD_READ:
{    //Incoming data; get ready to receive
    char buffer[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int bytes_received; 
    memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));

    struct sockaddr_in recvIn;
    int recv_length = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

    memset((void *)&recvIn, '\0', recv_length);

    bytes_received = recvfrom(wParam, buffer, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&recvIn, &recv_length);
    cout << inet_ntoa(recvIn.sin_addr) << "\n";

    break;
}
```

So I'm using Windows messages to see if I should check for packets. Receiving data works, I can read it and everything. But the recvIn variable doesn't get altered by recvfrom. So when I do the cout << inet_ntoa(recvIn.sin_addr) << "\n" it writes "0.0.0.0". I've googled this problem and most other people that had this problem forgot to initialize the recv_length. But I'm pretty sure I did that correctly here. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Or do I need to change something with the data that's being sent? Does the incoming data maybe not have the IP adress. Which is something I highly doubt, because I'm using TCP.

Thank you for you time, I hope I can get this solved!

Comment: Also I was wondering, why does the fromlen (last parameter of recvfrom) need to be a pointer, why not just the number itself? It seems pointless.

Comment: It needs to be a pointer because these APIs were written with future expansion in mind. You can give it some non-descript buffer and pass in its length, and it will fill in the buffer up to the current size of the structure and fill the length pointer with the actual length used.

Comment: `struct sockaddr_in recvIn; int recv_length = sizeof(struct sockaddr);` is suspicious: you're not applying `sizeof` to the type of the struct you're passing. Did you try code closer to the example in the docs? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: @JoãoMendes yeah, it's a connection-based socket (it's TCP) so that's gotta be it! Thanks :D

Comment: But when multiple connect to my server (which is what's supposed to be happening) how do I know which data corresponds with which client?

Comment: Ops. I deleted my comment and moved it to an answer. :/ Now, your response looks dangling... Anyway, check Dave S's answer below, it's probably what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TCP is a connection-oriented protocol. `from` and `fromlen` are meant to be used with connectionless protocols, such as UDP. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `recvfrom` ignores `from` and `fromlen` for connection-oriented sockets.

Answer (score 3):

For a connected TCP socket, you should use [getpeername()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpeername) to obtain the address of the remote socket.

Comment: To complement the answer, the link to the MSDN documentation for the function is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738533(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you SO much! ^^ that's just what I needed :D