# why i am getting Remote ip address 0.0.0.0 from recvfrom()?

Tags: c

I have a server listening on a port
The request is sent from my local client to the server running on my local pc.
Following is my code snippet

```
remote_len = sizeof(remote_addr);
if ((bytes=recvfrom(sockfd, buf, MAXBUFLEN , 0,
(struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, &remote_len)) <= 0) {
    exit(1);
}

printf("remote ip = %s\n",inet_ntoa(remote_addr.sin_addr));
```

When i print the ip i get 0.0.0.0 ??
Is this not the remote IP adrress which i am trying to print?
Edit : Its a TCP socket and i recevied buffer successfully.

Comment: What value did `recvfrom` return? Did it even succeed? What type of socket? Is it connected? etc...

Comment: yes it succeeded. Its a TCP socket

Comment: What is the value of remote_len? It's possible that you are getting the IPv6 loopback address.

Comment: remote_len is coming 0

Comment: Do you know what address actually connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [TCP recvfrom() doesn't store 'from'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873484/tcp-recvfrom-doesnt-store-from) - apparently it's not supported for TCP.  All you're seeing is the zero bytes that were originally there.  That's why `remote_len` returns 0 - because no address was set.

That link is to windows related docs; I don't see that behaviour in the Linux man page, which says only "may be used to receive data on a socket whether or not it is connection-oriented",  but at http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/recvman.html it says that recvfrom is for UDP.  It's not mentioned in Harbison + Steele, unfortunately, and I can't find a copy of Unix Network Programming.

Comment: thanks... now i am using getpeername() to get the remote address and also changed recvfrom() to recv()